# AJAX call to baikal shared calendar using sabreDAV

Tags: jquery, ajax, icalendar, webdav

I would like to figure out how to make an ajax call to a [baikal](http://sabre.io/baikal/) server to do GET, POST, OPTIONS, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, REPORT, PUT, MOVE, DELETE, LOCK, UNLOCK

I have used this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176917/adding-events-to-baikal-caldav-server-using-php) and got it working but I think I just don't know how to do a proper ajax call.

I make the call inside the same domain to avoid cross-domain issues for now.  I have used [CalDavZAP](https://www.inf-it.com/open-source/clients/caldavzap/) before and I can see they make a call using ajax but I just can't get it working even after looking at their code.

I have tried

```
var content = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR VERSION:2.0 CALSCALE:GREGORIAN BEGIN:VEVENT CREATED:20171020T123121Z LAST-MODIFIED:20171020T220236Z DTSTAMP:20171020T220236Z UID:m54url1l-6xwy-snnp-rg0h-7yl5kgsfbadg SUMMARY:this is new TRANSP:OPAQUE CLASS:PUBLIC DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20171025 DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20171026 END:VEVENT PRODID:-//Inf-IT//CalDavZAP 0.13.1//EN END:VCALENDAR';

$.ajax({
  type: 'PUT',
  url: 'http://cal.domain.ca/cal.php/calendars/user/default/crazychars.ics',
  beforeSend: function(req) {
    req.setRequestHeader('Prefer', 'return=representation');
    req.setRequestHeader('If-None-Match', '*');
  },
  username:'username',
  password:'password',
  contentType: 'text/calendar',
  processData: true,
  data: content,
  dataType: 'text', 
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(){
  console.log(data);  
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});//end of AJAX
```

After trying a lot of things the above now returns with 415 (Unsupported Media Type).  I have tried different types of contentType and additional headers with no better results.  After searching the internet I have no idea what else to do.  Baikal site doesn't provide examples of submitting to the server from where I have looked.

here is some request/response headers

```
Response Headers
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-
check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:application/xml; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 21 Oct 2017 11:44:12 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=98
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.4.6
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.31
X-Sabre-Version:3.1.3

Request Headers
Accept:text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en,fr;q=0.8
Authorization:Basic Z3N0bG91aXM6R3N0bG91aXM3OA==
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:345
Content-Type:text/calendar
Cookie:PHPSESSID=fqc0ctuskfv0cgaqeiq196gtf4; _ga=GA1.2.519255846.1496415686
Host:cal.smbservices.ca
If-None-Match:*
Origin:http://cal.domain.ca
Prefer:return=representation
Referer:http://cal.domain.ca/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I had was in my content variable.  In order to make an ajax call with a good format every line needed to finish with \r\n

```
var content = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\nVERSION:2.0\r\nCALSCALE:GREGORIAN\r\nBEGIN:VEVENT\r\nCREATED:20171020T123121Z\r\nLAST-MODIFIED:20171020T220236Z\r\nDTSTAMP:20171020T220236Z\r\nUID:m54url1l-6xwy-snnp-rg0h-7yl5kgsfbadg\r\nSUMMARY:superman\r\nTRANSP:OPAQUE\r\nCLASS:PUBLIC\r\nDTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20171030\r\nDTEND;VALUE=DATE:20171030\r\nEND:VEVENT\r\nPRODID:-//Inf-IT//CalDavZAP0.13.1//EN\r\nEND:VCALENDAR';
```